# Neo4j Spring Data Neo4j 4 cascade delete

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

In my Neo4j/SDN4 project I have a complex hierarchy of node entitles with a many linked object of a different types. I'm working on Like/Dislike functionality and every node in my system can have associated list of `Like` objects.

Right now I'm working on the delete query. The issue is that if I'm going to delete a root node of a big hierarchy, I have to find `Like` nodes associated with every type of the nodes in this structure and delete them separately.

So, I just wondering is there in Neo4j/SDN 4 an option.. something like cascade delete in RDBMS systems that can be used for this purpose in order to avoid a huge Cypher query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cascade delete is not available at the moment in neoj4-ogm/SDN (March 2017).

See a feature request in github https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/273

Your best option with SDN is to create a custom repository query that will delete both `Like` nodes and the root node:

```
@Query("MATCH (e:Entity)-[r]-(like) " +
       "WHERE e.prop = {prop} " +
       "DELETE e,r,like"
void deleteEntity(@Param("prop") String prop);
```

Answer (score 2):

In a similar case, we use [`apoc-triggers`](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_triggers). For example:

**Add trigger**

```
CALL apoc.trigger.add('removeHierarchy','
  UNWIND {deletedRelationships} AS rs WITH rs WHERE type(rs) = "LIKE" 
  MATCH (C:Node) WHERE C = endNode(rs) 
  DETACH DELETE C
', {phase:'before'});
```

**Initial tree**

```
UNWIND RANGE(1,100) as cid
WITH cid, 
     toInteger(rand()*cid) as pid
MERGE (P:Node {id: pid})
MERGE (C:Node {id: cid})
MERGE (P)-[:LIKE]->(C)
```

**Delete root**

```
MATCH (N:Node {id: 0}) DETACH DELETE N
```